# Adding sky in Python API

Tags: python, skybox

I can find a lot of examples about tools for creating a sky using the User Interface (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/sky.html), but the same cannot be said for the Python API. The only examples I found use the obsolete

```
bpy.context.scene.world.use_sky_paper
```

Which does not exist anymore.
Does anyone know how this can be replicated from Python?

Comment: I think so… I messed with material nodes a bit, so it shouldn’t be to different for the world. Try bpy.data.worlds[0].node_tree.nodes…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import bpy

sky_texture = bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexSky")
bg = bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes["Background"]
bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.links.new(bg.inputs["Color"], sky_texture.outputs["Color"])
```

You can then tweak the options like this:

```
sky_texture.sky_type = 'HOSEK_WILKIE' # or 'PREETHAM'
sky_texture.turbidity = 2.0
sky_texture.ground_albedo = 0.4
sky_texture.sun_direction = mathutils.Vector((1.0, 0.0, 1.0))  # add `import mathutils` at the beginning of the script
```

Comment: It works, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!